# Finding The Largest Number in a Nested List in Python

Tags: python

I would like to put the max number(s) to a new array, I've tried every thing that I can think of and none seem to work....(adding to an empty result array, concat, etc)

Obviously the for loop is printing the max function out with the proper numbers,
but I have a weak understanding of return vs print and how to capture values from a loop , etc.

```
list = [[21, 34, 345, 2], [555, 22, 6, 7], [94, 777, 65, 1], [23, 54, 12, 666]]
for i in list:
    print max(i)

345
555
777
666
```

Comment: `for .... : code_to_add_i_to_array`, basically., instead of `for ...: print i`.

Comment: It would be more conventional to convert your list to an array first and then take the max() of the array. 1) turn the nested list to a single, 2) convert the single list to array, 3 take max() /argmax in Numpy

Answer (score 5):

Just apply `max` to every sublist:

```
Python 2:   map(max, lists)
Python 3:   list(map(max, lists))
```

Of course the latter only works if you don't shadow the built-in `list` function with your variable (which is a bad idea anyway, so I used the name `lists` instead).

```
>>> lists = [[21, 34, 345, 2], [555, 22, 6, 7], [94, 777, 65, 1], [23, 54, 12, 666]]
>>> map(max, lists)
[345, 555, 777, 666]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
newArray = [max(i) for i in list]
```

search up List Comprehension, one of the most useful things about python.

Comment: Yes, I was checking out list comprehensions a bit yesterday....and may have even tried to hack something out with it to make this work, but no dice

Answer (score 0):

Try a list comprehension:

```
L = [[21, 34, 345, 2], [555, 22, 6, 7], [94, 777, 65, 1], [23, 54, 12, 666]]
maxes = [max(sublist) for sublist in L]
print(maxes)
# [345, 555, 777, 666]
```

Comment: ...and it works on lists with different lengths! I have to look into this bit more, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wow, folks are harsh today. I think that I understood your question;

```
new_list = [max(i) for i in list]
for k in new_list:
     print (k)
```

Comment: >>> new_list
[345, 555, 777, 666]

Answer (score 0):

**Working Example in *Python 2*** — Tested with Python ***2.6.9*** and ***2.7.10***

```python
L01 = [[21, 34, 345, 2], [555, 22, 6, 7], [94, 777, 65, 1], [23, 54, 12, 666]]
L02 = map(max, L01)
print(L02)
```

**Output**

```
[345, 555, 777, 666]
```

**Working Example in *Python 3*** — Tested with Python ***3.2.5*** and ***3.4.3*** and ***3.5.0***

The only difference is that `map()` is wrapped by `list()`.

```python
L01 = [[21, 34, 345, 2], [555, 22, 6, 7], [94, 777, 65, 1], [23, 54, 12, 666]]
L02 = list(map(max, L01))
print(L02)
```

**Output**

```
[345, 555, 777, 666]
```